# Overlay Divs with Images in Bootstrap 5 Responsive Design

Tags: css, css-position, overlay, bootstrap-5

I'm designing with basic a Bootstrap 5 starting point using a carousel inside a card body which is responsively working correctly full width in desktop, tablet and PC viewports.

The design however requires overlaying/stacking multiple same height and width divs on top of each other with z-index values  which need to behave in the same way: resize and maintain the card-body fill in the same way.

Using relative and absolute positioning with specifying values for width and height does seem to work, including 100%.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 0):

To insert elements as "layers" you need some prerequisites:

1. The parent must have a defined height (it cannot be in percentage, nor automatic, it must be px, em, rem, cm...).
2. The parent must have position set to relative, absolute, or fixed.
3. Children need to be with

   .layer{position: absolute, top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%}
4. It is not necessary to use z-index if the next layer is the last child of the parent

```html
<style>
    p{
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .carroussel-item{
         position: relative;
    }
    .layers{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="carroussel-item">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/tech">

    <div class="layers layer-1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/nature">

        <div class="layers layer-2">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/people">

            <div class="layers layer-3">
                <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was thinking about a base image the same like an aperture to maintain the design as it resizes, what are your thoughts on this or are absolutes looking for hard values to define the space they need to fit? I'm not sure how I would do this but just a thought.

Comment: I don't suppose setting those values dynamically with JS would be a solution?

Comment: @BaMa Using JS is possible, but it will slow down your code. But it follows the same rule. As long as the JS throws a defined value (like px) the rest of the code will start working.

Comment: Thank you @Luis, would using @ media work? I don't know how to implement those but I think they work off max-width, say 368px for mobile, 768px tablet... ? Thank you.

Comment: to be clear the divs would not be nested per your example but stacked as below and they would need to fill out the outer div/card 100% to the column width according to design:  
<div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="carroussel-item">
        <div id="layer-1" class="layers layer-1">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/tech" alt="" />
        </div>

<!-- repeat 
["
"https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/nature",
"https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/people",
"https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch"
"]
-->

    </div>
</div>

Comment: @BaMa I think I understand. I did an update. Before the layers it is necessary to have the main content. This time the size of the div is defined by the content. But in this case it works because the images have the same dimension, I'm not sure it would look so good with different dimensions.

Comment: Thanks @Luis Lubo ... sorry if not clear, but the divs *not nested* inside each other like  your example:

<div class="carroussel-item">
   <div class="layers layer-1">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/tech">
         <div class="layers layer-2">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/nature">
               <div class="layers layer-3">
                  ...
They will be stacked, always the same size div/image like this:
<div class="carroussel-item">
   <div layer 1><img 1 /></div>
   <div layer 2><img 2 /></div>
   <div layer 3><img 3 /></div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

```css
body, html { height: 100%; margin: 0; }
.bg { 
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/XJDwDfH/i.webp"); 
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.bg div { width: 70px; height: 70px; }
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div style="background-color:coral;"></div>
</div>
```